# How to use $this in PHP class to return requested row only?

Tags: php, class, scope

I want to chain my class's methods, such as in this way,

```
$article = New Article();
$article->getRow()->addImages();
```

Because sometimes I don't need to add images to the article that I request,

```
$article->getRow();
```

This is my code,

```
class Article
{
    protected $connection;
    public $total;
    public $item;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->connection = new Database(DSN,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
        $this->connection->connect();
    }

    public function getRow($options = array())
    {
        // Prepare the SQL.
        $sql = "
            SELECT*
            FROM article AS p
            WHERE p.article_id = 'home'
        ";

        $this->total = $this->connection->countRows($sql,array(
            $property->type
        ));


        $this->item = $this->connection->fetchRow($sql,array(
            $property->type
        ));

        return $this;
    }

    public function addImages() {

        $this->item['images']['items'] = array(
            0 => "image 1",
            1 => "image 2"
        );

        $this->item['images']['total'] = 2;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

result for `$article->getRow()->addImages()`,

```
Article Object
(
    [connection:protected] => Database Object
        (
            [connection:protected] => PDO Object
                (
                )

            [dsn:protected] => mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx
            [username:protected] => xxx
            [password:protected] => xxx
        )
    [item] => Array
        (
            [url] => hello
            [title] => world
            [images] => Array
                (
                    [items] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => image 1
                            [1] => image 2
                        )

                    [total] => 2
                )

        )

    [total] => 1

}
```

As you can see that `[connection:protected]` is always in the result, and `[total] => 1` for the article as well.

But how can I get the result in like this below straight to the requested/ intended data **without** doing this `$article->getRow()->addImages()->item`,

```
  Array
    (
        [url] => hello
        [title] => world
        [images] => Array
            (
                [items] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => image 1
                        [1] => image 2
                    )

                [total] => 2
            )

    )
```

Is it possible?

I find that `$article->getRow()->addImages()->item` is 'ugly' for getting a simple data.

Comment: You can add `url`, `title` and `images` properties to your object and remove `connection` and `total` properties using unset(). Then return this modified object.

Comment: `I cant imagine you will have to send connection information each time. ` how would you do it then?

Answer (score 1):

When using `$this` to use method chaining, you inherently pass the whole object in your return. This is how we can use method chaining, but you seem fully aware of that. What you desire seems a bit odd though:

- You want to use method chaining (meaning your return value is `$this`)
- You want to receive only your `item` property (meaning your return value is not `$this`)

Those seem mutually exclusive as I seriously think a method can not return two different things.

**But**

you can have your `addImages()` function return what you desire. Note that this solution prevents any further method chaining...

```
public function addImages() {

    $this->item['images']['items'] = array(
        0 => "image 1",
        1 => "image 2"
    );

    $this->item['images']['total'] = 2;

    return $this->item; // HERE you return your item instead
}
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the answer. What I wanted was indeed odd!